# Parsing of list of bits in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of 64 bits.

```
['11111111', '11111111', '10001111', '11111110', '11011011', '11111111', '01011011', '10000111']
```

Here each and every bit represents a feature. If a bit is 1 then that particular feature is supported else not.

Is there any way were i can check the bit and just return its associated feature if it is 1.

`Input : 1111111`

`Output: If all bits are one then I need to print all eight features masked in it.`

Comment: Can you give an example input and the result you want to get for it? It will help us help you.

Comment: What do you want to return, the index of the item?

Comment: @KaasiasKomplex item itself i should return

Comment: What is your input and what is the desired output? (whatever you wrote there under the "PS" is totally unclear).

Comment: Just so you know, you don't really have a list of 64 bits. You have a list containing 8 strings, each of size 8, consisting of the characters `'0'` or `'1'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could do something like:

```
bits = ['11111111', '11111111', '10001111', '11111110', '11011011', '11111111', '01011011', '10000111']

# to produce features mapping dynamically:
# features = {i:"feature " + str(i) for i in range(0,64)}
features = {0: 'feature 0', 1: 'feature 1', 2: 'feature 2', 3: 'feature 3', 4: 'feature 4', 5: 'feature 5', 6: 'feature 6', 7: 'feature 7', 8: 'feature 8', 9: 'feature 9', 10: 'feature 10', 11: 'feature 11', 12: 'feature 12', 13: 'feature 13', 14: 'feature 14', 15: 'feature 15', 16: 'feature 16', 17: 'feature 17', 18: 'feature 18', 19: 'feature 19', 20: 'feature 20', 21: 'feature 21', 22: 'feature 22', 23: 'feature 23', 24: 'feature 24', 25: 'feature 25', 26: 'feature 26', 27: 'feature 27', 28: 'feature 28', 29: 'feature 29', 30: 'feature 30', 31: 'feature 31', 32: 'feature 32', 33: 'feature 33', 34: 'feature 34', 35: 'feature 35', 36: 'feature 36', 37: 'feature 37', 38: 'feature 38', 39: 'feature 39', 40: 'feature 40', 41: 'feature 41', 42: 'feature 42', 43: 'feature 43', 44: 'feature 44', 45: 'feature 45', 46: 'feature 46', 47: 'feature 47', 48: 'feature 48', 49: 'feature 49', 50: 'feature 50', 51: 'feature 51', 52: 'feature 52', 53: 'feature 53', 54: 'feature 54', 55: 'feature 55', 56: 'feature 56', 57: 'feature 57', 58: 'feature 58', 59: 'feature 59', 60: 'feature 60', 61: 'feature 61', 62: 'feature 62', 63: 'feature 63'}

for ind, bit in enumerate(reversed("".join(bits))):
    if bit == '1':
        print "Feature " + features[ind] + " turned on"
```

Where using:

- `reversed` - because bits are read from LSB to MSB so we need to iterate from right to left.
- `enumerate` - because we want to get the associated index to check in our mapping what is the feature name/attributes.
- `"".join(bits)` - because we want to be able to join all the items on the list to one iterable object we can go through.

Answer (score 0):

You may unwrap the string in variable for each feature as:

```
>>> my_bit = '11111110'
>>> feat_1, feat_2, feat_3, feat_4, feat_5, feat_6, feat_7, feat_8 = my_bit
>>> print feat_1, feat_2, feat_3, feat_4, feat_5, feat_6, feat_7, feat_8
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
```

Now, you may check for each feature as:

```
if feat_1:
     # Do something
else:
     # Do something else
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on your way to enumerate the features. if you enumerate your features from 0 to 63 it would be something like this:

```
import math

testdata = ['11111111', '11111111', '10001111', '11111110', '11011011', '11111111', '01011011', '10000111']

def test_feature(data, i):
        block = math.floor(i/8)
        pos = i % 8

        if data[block][pos] == '1':
                return True

        return False

print(testdata)
print(test_feature(testdata, 0))
print(test_feature(testdata, 3))
print(test_feature(testdata, 8))
print(test_feature(testdata, 17))
print(test_feature(testdata, 33))
print(test_feature(testdata, 63))
```

However, you can easily adjust this method to match other enumerations.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a list of features first.

```
feat_list = ['f1','f2','f3','f4','f6','f7','f8']

bit_list = ['11111111', '11111111', '10001111', '11111110', '11011011', '11111111', '01011011', '10000111']
```

Then make a function.

```
def extract_feature(bit_string):
    result = []
    for ind, bit in enumerate(bit_string):
        if bit == '1':
            result.append(feat_list[ind])
    return result
```

Then use a loop to get features for each bit string.

```
for bit_string in bit_list:
    print extract_feature(bit_string)
```

Note that, it is not very efficient, but it is verbose so that a newbie can understand.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether I've understood exactly :)

```
def extract_features(x, f):
    return [f[i] for i, elem in enumerate(x) if x[i] == '1']


features = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
x = '11111111'    
y = '10101010'

print (extract_features(x, features))
print (extract_features(y, features))

"""
<Output>
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
['a', 'c', 'e', 'g']
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def f0(): print "executing feature0"
def f1(): print "executing feature1"
def f2(): print "executing feature2"
def f3(): print "executing feature3"
def f4(): print "executing feature4"
def f5(): print "executing feature5"
def f6(): print "executing feature6"
def f7(): print "executing feature7"


def run_features(mask):
    for index, bit in (enumerate(mask[::-1])):
        if bit == '1':
            features[index]()

bits = [
    '11111111', '11111111', '10001111', '11111110',
    '11011011', '11111111', '01011011', '10000111'
]

features = [
    f0, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7
]

for mask in bits:
    run_features(mask)
    print '-' * 80
```